# Stack or append Makefile targets

Tags: docker, makefile, docker-compose

I have built the following `Makefile` to automate Docker a bit (reduce memorising and typing long commands, that is).

```makefile
.PHONY: help build rebuild up down start stop destroy restart enter ps enable-xdebug disable-xdebug

COMPOSE_FILE = docker-compose.yml
PROJECT = my_project

help: ## Show the available commands.
    @awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "} /^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## / {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)

build: ## Build docker images
    docker-compose -p $(PROJECT) -f $(COMPOSE_FILE) build --parallel --pull

rebuild: ## Force rebuild of docker images from scratch
    docker-compose -p $(PROJECT) -f $(COMPOSE_FILE) build --parallel --pull --no-cache

up: ## Build and start docker containers
    docker-compose -p $(PROJECT) -f $(COMPOSE_FILE) up -d

start: ## Start docker containers
    docker-compose -p $(PROJECT) -f $(COMPOSE_FILE) start

down: ## Remove docker containers
    docker-compose -p $(PROJECT) -f $(COMPOSE_FILE) down

stop: ## Stop docker containers
    docker-compose -p $(PROJECT) -f $(COMPOSE_FILE) stop

restart: stop up ## Restart docker containers
```

(I included the `restart` target to demonstrate Makefile targets triggering other targets.)

Now, the *problem* I have is that every change I have to make to target `make build` also needs to be changed in `make rebuild` (they're essentially the same command, minus the `--no-cache` flag.)

The question is: Is there a way I can make `rebuild` call the existing `build` target + a append  `--no-cache` ?

So it would look something like

```makefile
build: ## Build docker images
    docker-compose -p $(PROJECT) -f $(COMPOSE_FILE) build --parallel --pull

rebuild: ## Force rebuild of docker images from scratch
    ${build} --no-cache
```

Comment: You should almost never need `docker build --no-cache`; do you have a specific setup where you need it?  Standard Make style would be to have a `$(DOCKER_BUILD_OPTIONS)` variable, so that you could `make build DOCKER_BUILD_OPTIONS=--no-cache`, but this shouldn't usually be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put the command in a variable; most makefiles make extensive use of variables so that things can be changed in one place:

```
DOCKER_COMPOSE = docker-compose
DOCKER_CMD = $(DOCKER_COMPOSE) -p $(PROJECT) -f $(COMPOSE_FILE)
```

then use `$(DOCKER_CMD)` in all your recipes.  Then:

```
DOCKER_BUILD = $(DOCKER_CMD) build --parallel --pull

build:
        $(DOCKER_BUILD)
rebuild:
        $(DOCKER_BUILD) --no-cache
```

Alternatively, you can use [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) to do it like this:

```
NO_CACHE =
DOCKER_BUILD = $(DOCKER_CMD) build --parallel --pull $(NO_CACHE)

build:
        $(DOCKER_BUILD)
rebuild: build
rebuild: NO_CACHE = --no-cache
```